# Logging out of Gmail logs me out of SO

Tags: support, login, logout, google-openid

This seems to be a recent behavior.

I use Google to log in to SO. In my normal browsing browser, I don't typically remain logged in to Google. So, if I need to (rarely) log in to SO, I will click the Google link, connect in to SO, and, then, fire up a new window, bounce over to Gmail, and log out of Google.

Before, I would retain my SO login, but be logged out of Google.

Is there a new setting that I need to check to disable this? I've seen other posts where folks want to log out of SO and have that log out of Google as well, so I can see there needing to be flexibility on this. But I would mostly prefer to not have a persistent Google log in if I can possibly avoid it.

Comment: As this question was bounced to the frontpage, does this error still persist Will, or can it be closed?

Comment: There isn't any communication with Stack Overflow and Google after a successful login, and logging out of Google would in no way affect your session on Stack Overflow. Something else must be going on in your browser that is clearing cookies. If you are using Chrome, you may be signing out of Chrome completely and not just Google? Do you get logged out of other sites when logging out of Google?

Comment: @animuson, as this Q is 3+ years old I doubt it still reproduces.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm aware. It's still worth explaining that this isn't possible from our side (and never was), for people who might stumble upon this in the future.

Comment: @Luuklag yea, this problem isn't occurring for me any more. I have no idea how this got back to the front page.

Comment: @WillHartung a spammy answer did so.